# NetworkVariable - variable not updating correct (Netcode, Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building a turn based game with Unity and Netcode.

My connections work and I receive expected behavior on the NetworkManager.

Except for one thing...

I have a server variable, that should be aligned on all clients. It's the index of the player (turn) in the game (`CurrentPlayerIndex`). The turn should change after a action has been done, but for testing I just made it a button action, so that all clients can change turn (change the `CurrentPlayerIndex`).

I made it work, so that CurrentPlayerIndex changes correctly on all clients, when one client change the `CurrentPlayerIndex`. It works so that the variable in a visual label updates with the same variable on all clients.

The problem is that the variable doesn't get stored on the client, so when I increase the `CurrentPlayerIndex` on one client, it shows the correctly increased `CurrentPlayerIndex` in the label BUT when I increase the same (already increased) variable on the same client, it just starts from the local index instead.

Let me explain...

I have two clients. Client1 and Client2. `CurrentPlayerIndex` starts on 0. When I click "increase" three times on Client1, `CurrentPlayerIndex` increases to `3`. This is displayed on both Client1 and Client2. But when I click "increase" 2 times on Client2, the `CurrentPlayerIndex` starts from 0 again and increases to `3`. When I click "increase" on Client1 again, the `CurrentPlayerIndex` increases to 4 and so on...

I expect that I misunderstand something about the local client and server behavior, but in this case I just want a "global" variable, that can be affected by all clients and aligned on all clients.

Here's the code snippet:

```
    [SerializeField]
    public NetworkVariable<int> CurrentPlayerIndex = new NetworkVariable<int>();


    public override void OnNetworkSpawn() {
        CurrentPlayerIndex.OnValueChanged += OnCurrentPlayerIndexChanged;
    }

    public override void OnNetworkDespawn()  {
        CurrentPlayerIndex.OnValueChanged -= OnCurrentPlayerIndexChanged;
    }

    
    public void OnCurrentPlayerIndexChanged(int previous, int current)  {
        UIManager.Instance.gameMenuLabel.text = "Player " + CurrentPlayerIndex.Value + "'s turn";
    }


    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    public void ChangeTurnServerRpc(int nextPlayerIndex) {
        CurrentPlayerIndex.Value = nextPlayerIndex;
    }


    public void ChangeTurn() {

        int nextPlayerIndex = 0;

        if (CurrentPlayerIndex.Value+1 < 5) {
            nextPlayerIndex = CurrentPlayerIndex.Value+1;
        } 

        ChangeTurnServerRpc(nextPlayerIndex);
    }
```

Comment: "At a high level, a NetworkVariable is a way to synchronize a property ("variable") between a server and client(s) without having to use custom messages or RPCs." - Do you need the RPC?